# It is possible to deactivate the InternetExplorer Silverlight Add-On with PowerShell?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, powershell, automated-tests

it is possible to deactivate the InternetExplorer Silverlight Add-On?

Later I want to open the Internet Explorer with the Powershell command:

- $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start IE in no-addons mode.  There is a command line switch for this, I think.  Check out what the link in Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools does.

You can remove Silverlight's COM registration from the registry.  Then IE won't be able to instantiate it.

There may be other solutions.